# having problems to understand while loops in pyramid

Tags: python

can anyone explain how to create pyramid using while loops in python?

```
userInput = int(input("Please enter the amount of rows: "))
 row = 0
  while(row < userInput):
   row += 1
   spaces = userInput - row




spaces_counter = 0
while(spaces_counter < spaces):
    print(" ", end='')
    spaces_counter += 1

num_stars = 2*row-1
while(num_stars > 0):
    print("*", end='')
    num_stars -= 1

print()
```

it would be so much if anyone explain that code to me..thx

Comment: What *do* you understand? Where *exactly* are you stuck?

Comment: i'm stuck at space_counter

Answer (score 0):

You just need to fix your indentations:

```
userInput = int(input("Please enter the amount of rows: "))
row = 0
while(row < userInput):
    row += 1
    spaces = userInput - row

    spaces_counter = 0
    while(spaces_counter < spaces):
        print(" ", end='')
        spaces_counter += 1

    num_stars = 2*row-1
    while(num_stars > 0):
        print("*", end='')
        num_stars -= 1

    print()    # next line
```

Output

```
Please enter the amount of rows: 5
    *
   ***
  *****
 *******
*********
```